# Find a specific word in text files between double quotation marks

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many text files and need to locate certain words that may exist in the context of the file but need only those that are in quotation marks.

Example: Find in the text below the word "search" only if in quotes (the word "search" may vary).

```
1.  text text text text text text search text
2.  text "search text text text text" text
3.  text "SEARCH text text text text" text
```

For this precise example, I would expect only the words of line 2 and 3.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Hi squiguy. I thought of using Notepad++

Comment: This is harder than you might expect, using regexes alone.  Consider this:  `text "text text" text TARGET text "text text" text "text"`.  You and I can count open/close quotes and see that TARGET isn't quoted.  But try explaining that to the regex engine in a generalized way that will work for all possible levels of quoting.

Comment: @DavidO - I attempted to address this in my solution, but do tell if you detect a flaw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee that there'll be only one set of quotes, then

```
/".*search.*"/i
```

should do.  But if there can be more than one pair of quotes, then you have to ensure that an even number of quotes have been passed, lest you mistake a closing quote for an opening quote:

```
/^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*search[^"]*"/i
```

Here's [a demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%5B%5E%22%5Cn%5D%2a%28%22%5B%5E%22%5Cn%5D%2a%22%5B%5E%22%5Cn%5D%2a%29%2a%22%5B%5E%22%5Cn%5D%2asearch%5B%5E%22%5Cn%5D%2a%22&input=1.%20text%20text%20text%20text%20text%20text%20search%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A2.%20text%20%22search%20text%20text%20text%20text%22%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A3.%20text%20%22SEARCH%20text%20text%20text%20text%22%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A4.%20text%20%22hello%20world%22%20test%20%22search%20text%20text%22%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A5.%20text%20%22hello%20world%22%20search%20%22text%20text%20text%22%0D%0A).  (Note that the demo contains `\n`s purely for presentation purposes.)  **If you see two `#`s in the demo regex, please replace them with parentheses `(` `)`—it is a limitation of the way RegexPal encodes its data in the URL.**

Answer (score 0):

I you want all waords between double quotes, I would simply use `grep`:

```
 grep -E -o '".*"' inputfile
```

I f you want only the first word:

```
sed  -E 's/.+"([[:alpha:]]+) .*/\1/' inputfile
```

Comment: he wants the matching word, but only if it's in quotes.  This returns all words within quotes.  I would change it to `grep -E -o -i '"word.*"' inputfile`